# Autofitting column in combination with setting numberformat will autofit using unformatted text as measurement

Tags: epplus

When I use EPPlus to autofit a column that is formatted as a date string, the autofit mechanism is using the unformatted string as measurement for how wide the column should become.

Is it a bug or did I do something wrong?

Code

```
sheet.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm";
sheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

Result:

[image: autofit using date formatting]

widening the second column in excel

[image: autofit using date formatting then widening datefield column in excel]

Autofit using no formatting, notice that the second column is having the same width as the supposed-to-autofit column in the first picture.

[image: autofit without formatting]

For completion, here is the result when no autofit is used

[image: no autofit]

Comment: Works fine for me.  What version of EPPlus are you using? Are you doing additonal steps to the columns or cells in the code after the two lines you posted?

Comment: Nothing added, version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your font settings either in your code or globally in excel.  Try running this test (I am posting this as an answer since I cannot fit it in a comment):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Auto_Col_Fomat_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (DateTime)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i; row[1] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i); row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Auto_Col_Fomat.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var sheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

        sheet.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm";
        sheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

If this shows the same thing you may have changed your default excel font or zoom which means you may have to set the font in code to `Body Font` size 11 (at least that was 2013 uses).  If it doesnt show post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Here is my work around:

First call AutoFitColumns, then add some padding to the column that has a special format:

```
cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
sheet.Column(2).Width *= 1.25;
```